# Bash script - Auto fill answer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script that has several questions, is it possible to automatically fill the answers ?

```
./script.sh install
```

answers in order `y 2 1 n n`

How can I do that in bash ?

edit: is it possible to only pass the first answer ?

```
echo "y" | install
```

and let the choice to the user to answer the next questions ?

Comment: As in proceeds without user input? Or just allows the user to hit enter to proceed with the default?

Comment: As in proceeds without user input

Comment: You will need to build a wrapper and if you know the order and values of the arguments exactly, you can either use `expect` or echo to pass on the arguments to the original script. You can find plenty such examples of in SE/SO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would pass a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to stdin:

```
./script.sh install <<EOF
y
2
1
n
n
EOF
```

If you want it on one line, you can also use `echo`:

```
echo -e "y\n2\n1\nn\nn" | ./script.sh install
```

However, I prefer the here document solution since it is IMHO more readable.

Comment: Then you may want to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat ...

Comment: @supertrainee Sure it is possible, isn't this obvious? Simply pass just one answer to stdin.

Comment: @hek2mgl i don't understant how to do it, if i just pass one answer i can't enter the answer for the next questions i get an infinite loop ...

Comment: @supertrainee Oh sorry, got it.I admit that I thought it would just work but it doesn't. Hard to say, I don't know a way a the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Another method is the use of a **here string** (which has the benefit of eliminating the one-line pipe, but not the subshell):

```
./script.sh install <<<$(printf "y\n2\n1\nn\nn\n")
```

You may also be able to rely on the printf trick of printing all elements through a single format specifier and use process substitution (or use with the here string syntax above):

```
./script.sh install < <(printf "%c\n" y 2 1 n n)
```

Comment: I thougt about a here-string as too, but I couldn't find any benefits compared to `echo -e | ...` in this case because it still requires an additional command to be launched. IMHO `echo -e ... | ` is more readable

Comment: Yep, your right, no discernible benefit, just another way of skinning the same cat.

Comment: Yeah, no worries, I just wanted to mention it.