# How to autofill source keystore password when importing pkcs12 to keystore

Tags: java, bash, keytool

I can import a p12 keystore to keystore. With the storepass, I can pre-fill the passwort of the destination keystore.

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.server.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -storepass $PWD
```

However, I am still asked for the source keystore password:

```
Enter source keystore password:
```

How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-srcstorepass` . Also better use `-deststorepass` (which is documented) not `-storepass` (which just happens to work in the code). See `keytool -importkeystore -help`.

Note if the p12 contains a privatekey-and-cert (as it usually does) and you make the dest=JKS storepass different from the src=P12 combined-store&key-pass, the privatekey within the JKS still has its key(entry) pass the same as the p12 *source*. This means any program wanting to use the privatekey from the JKS must support different values for storepass and keypass, and some don't.

Comment: Could you please name an example?

Comment: john: for a start, anything using the [JSSE-configuration-sysprops](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-A41282C3-19A3-400A-A40F-86F4DA22ABA9). I've also seen plenty of programs -- some _intended_ as Q&D or example but used anyway -- that do this. By coincidence I just now looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78231277/pkix-failed-when-using-custom-sslcontext-with-custom-keystore-and-truststore which does so, albeit with an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (maybe not the best) is applying the answer provided here:

[Bash script - Auto fill answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563819/bash-script-auto-fill-answer)

```
echo -e "mypassword" | keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kafka.server.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore kafka.server.keystore.jks -storepass $CA_PWD
```

Comment: This above solutions works, the solution from dave_thompson_085 is cleaner and better

Comment: Instead of using echo, you can also just use the ```-srcstorepass``` parameter.