# PKIX failed when using custom SSLcontext with custom keyStore and trustStore

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, keystore, pkix

I'm trying to reach a Rest WebService that should send me a JSON response,
for which I need to expose a certificate in a KeyStore that lets me authenticate, meanwhile I need the same certificate to be in the TrustStore of my App so that my client recognizes the WebService.
I succesfully put the keys in the SSLContext, but I didn't have the same luck with the TrustStore, since it keeps giving me `PKIX Path Building Failed`.

This is the method that defines the Context:

```
    public SSLContext defineTrustManager() {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory;
        try {
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
            X509TrustManager defaultX509CertificateTrustManager = null;
            
            for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager ) {
                    defaultX509CertificateTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                    break;
                }
            }
            FileInputStream myKeys = new FileInputStream("./certificatiAddizionali");
            KeyStore myTrustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            myTrustStore.load(myKeys, "".toCharArray());
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(myTrustStore);

            X509TrustManager myTrustManager = null;
            for (TrustManager tm : trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
                if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager ) {
                    myTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tm;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            X509TrustManager finalDefaultTm = defaultX509CertificateTrustManager;
            X509TrustManager finalMyTm = myTrustManager;

            X509TrustManager wrapper = new X509TrustManager() {
                private X509Certificate[] mergeCertificates() {
                    ArrayList<X509Certificate> resultingCerts = new ArrayList<>();
                    resultingCerts.addAll(Arrays.asList(finalDefaultTm.getAcceptedIssuers()));
                    resultingCerts.addAll(Arrays.asList(finalMyTm.getAcceptedIssuers()));
                    return resultingCerts.toArray(new X509Certificate[resultingCerts.size()]);
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return mergeCertificates();
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    try {
                        finalMyTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                    } catch (CertificateException e) {
                        finalDefaultTm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    finalDefaultTm.checkClientTrusted(mergeCertificates(), authType);
                }
            };
            String keyPassphrase = "";

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("./certificatiKeystore"), keyPassphrase.toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyPassphrase.toCharArray());
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[] { wrapper }, null);
            SSLContext.setDefault(context);
            return  context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        
    }
```

This is the test method I'm using to reach WS and check the response:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/getSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void  test(HttpServletRequest request)  {
         HttpResponse response = null;
         
    try {
   
        SSLContext sslContext  = defineTrustManager();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        response =httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("mytesturl.com"));
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In debug I can clearly see that the certificates are present and read by the TrustManagerFactory, so then why it keeps giving me the PKIX error?
Ps. both the keystore and truststore have no password.

Comment: Can you try to have a wrapper class of `X509ExtendedTrustmanager` and overriding all of the methods instead of creating a wrapper class of  `X509TrustManager`

Comment: It's extremely rare (normally impossible) that the 'same certificate' can be used for client authentication and ALSO as an anchor to validate server. Your code uses different _filenames_ but of course different files can contain the same cert or different certs, while a single file also can contain multiple (different) certs, so that doesn't help. Since you have the `javax.net.debug` log, it should show the server chain as received, and the trust anchors you are configuring, so just look at them and see if the combination is valid.